# Ng-show button only on specific pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 buttons which I only want to show when it's on any other page other than the index page, is there a way to do that?

**Index.html:**

```
<body>
    <header ng-include="'views/header.html'"></header>
    <main ng-view></main>
</body>
```

**Sub Page.html:**

```
<div>
  <table id="tabletodownload" ng-show="auditoriums === 'none'" style="border:1px solid #000;">

    <tr> 
        <th> Customer Name </th> 
        <th> Order Value </th> 
        <th> Ordered On</th> 
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="audit in auditoriums| limitTo: 1 - auditoriums.length">
         <td>{{audit.NAME}}</td>
         <td>{{audit.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER}}</td>
         <td>{{audit.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}</td>
         <td>{{audit.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnDownload"> Download as CSV</button>
```

I need to place the button in my index page but only shows when in my sub page.html. Why? Because I have no idea why my button function (download table to csv function) doesn't work when I place it any other place other than the index page.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it , but you need to share your code

Comment: Looks like your `index` page is a wrapper for the `ng-view`, would you mind showing how you were trying to add the `button` to your `index` page?

Comment: I am trying to place it above the ng-view. But to have it shows up only when im on other pages other than index page itself

Comment: `ng-view` works with the `$routerProvider` and you need a html template which contains your button. `ng-include` just loads html file template and can be used without `ng-view`/router. There are different ways to achieve what you are after. Event `ng-if`, `ng-switch` would work.

Comment: Actually you should find a way why it's not working in any view & only in index.html. If must want to do in index.html then, you can make use of `$rootScope` variable. In that particular page controller for which you want to show the button set some var `$rootScope.isDownloadButton = true;` in other controllers keep it false onload. Then, in index.html have condition on button element as `ng-if="$root.isDownloadButton"`